# Looking for a regular expression to work on a list of comma separated values

Tags: windows-7, windows, shell-script, regex, ultraedit

I have line of 3 long numbers separated by comma.
What I want to do is to delete the number in the middle, and leave only first number and last number separated by a comma.

Currently:

```
123456789123,723456789123456,834567885544334
123456789125,723456789123457,834567885544333
123456789126,723456789123458,834567885544337
```

Desired result:

```
123456789123,834567885544334
123456789125,834567885544333
123456789126,834567885544337
```

I tried doing this, but it didn't work with these regular expressions:

- regular expression to find string:       `%[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+`
- regular expression to replace string:    `^1,^2`

**Which regular expression actually does what I want to achieve?**

Note - I'm currently using an application called Ultraedit that runs on Windows 7, if you recommend a better text editing application for Windows that can solve my problem please let me know.

Comment: I edited your question, if you are unhappy with the changes feel free to revert or edit it again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply replace the middle number of each line with nothing.

### In the editor

That is, in your editor, search-and-replace the regex

```
,[0-9]+,
```

(which only matches numbers with commas on both sides, which for your input is just the middle number) with a single comma:

```
,
```

I assume Ultraedit supports regex search-and-replace. If not, try Notepad++, which I know does.

### From the command line

Since you tagged your question [shell-script](/questions/tagged/shell-script), here's how to do it from the command-line.

### sed

Use `sed`, a standard Linux command also available for Windows as part of Cygwin or GnuWin32:

```
C:\>sed -e 's/,[0-9]+,/,/g' filename.txt
```

### Powershell

Jens pointed out that you can also do it in Windows Powershell; see [this explanation](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/01/17/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-replace-characters-in-a-text-file.aspx).

Comment: It would not work if you replace the middle sub-expression with an empty string.  You may, however, replace it with a single comma to get the desired effect.

Comment: Oops, that was stupid of me. Fixed.

Comment: Without Cygwin, you could use the powershell: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/01/17/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-replace-characters-in-a-text-file.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Regex syntax varies from application to application. I am unfamiliar with Ultredit and will give a generaql anser

Your regex lacks capturing parentheses

([0-9]+),[0-9]+,([0-9]+)

Answer (score 2):

In order to replace text, one needs to tag the proper sub-expression using parentheses.

In UltraEdit, you must search for the following regular expression:

```
 %^([0-9]+^),[0-9]+,^([0-9]+^)
```

Answer (score 2):

Awk Equivalent!

`echo "$Variable" | awk 'FS="," { print $1","$3 } '`